# is it possible to send a directed flash message in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, flash-message

this is kind of a dumb question, but is it possible to send a

```
flash[:success]
```

directed to a certain user other than the current user on the screen? in one of my controllers i have

```
if @article.up_votes.count > 10
    flash[:success ] = 'something'
end
```

is it possible to send that flash to the owner of the article? as opposed to my own screen? or is there another way to do this?

i tried looking through

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Flash/FlashHash.html#method-i-notice

but couldn't find any method that would help. maybe i am reading it wrong? is there a way to achieve the same effect then?

thank you...

Comment: What do you mean, "to another user"? You're talking about an intra-app messaging system, which is nothing like flash scope at all.

Comment: you will have to use pusher service or even long-polling will help you. i guess without that u cant get this.

Comment: create a message table, check on every page.

Answer (score 0):

Not using flash, you'd have to try something else,  there are lots of ways to go about it,  but flash isn't one of them.  Well,  you could still use flash,  but it wouldn't be to send from one user to another,  you could cause a flash message to appear for the user being notified.

First thing to figure out is how do you notify the other user,  when would he get that notification,  do you want him to get notified anytime he using your site?  Or only if he does something specific on your site?

Answer (score 0):

For what I know the best way to go, maybe the only way actually is push notifications. There are many ways to achieve this but I think faye should be the easiest.

See this screencast to understand it and later. You want to have a channel for each user so it will be the one to get that message. Further search for private pub so nobody's can listen to others channel

http://railscasts.com/episodes/260-messaging-with-faye

http://railscasts.com/episodes/316-private-pub

Answer (score 0):

As ismaelga mentioned I also think push notifications is the way to go (WebSockets).

In addition to Faye you can use a hosted solution called Pusher (pusher.com).

Here is a really short description about how Pusher can help you. Bassically all users using your application listens for messages on a WebSocket-server (through JavaScript). In this case Pusher. You can then send messages to Pusher via your Rails application. When you send a message to Pusher, all users will instantly be notified about the new message via JavaScript (through the WebSocket). To only notify a specific user you can use Pusher's "private channels"-feature.

Pusher have some really good documentation on how to use their service: http://pusher.com/docs/javascript_quick_start

This picture (taken from Nettuts+) might also give you a better understanding of how Pusher works: http://d2o0t5hpnwv4c1.cloudfront.net/1059_pusher/pusher_websocket.png

Hope this helps a bit.